# IN and NOT IN HiveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql, qubole

I am new to HiveQL and is IN and NOT IN supported in it? Especially when using Qubole?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vId FROM table1 
WHERE d.columnOne = "123"
AND NOT d.columnTwo
AND timestamp between 1523550000000 AND 1523930000000 
AND NOT h.columnThree regexp "000.000.000.00|111.111.111.11|222.22.222.22" 
AND vId in (select vId from table2 where colOne regexp "000|111|222")
```

my error is

> "Unsupported language features in query: "

Comment: I'm thinking more that the `AND NOT` is the unsupported part. That doesn't look like valid SQL but I am certainly not a hive expert. `IN` and `NOT IN` seem to be [supported](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_data-access/content/hive-013-feature-subqueries-in-where-clauses.html)

Comment: "AND NOT d.columnTwo" doesn't seem right to me. Also, are you sure regexp are supported? try a simpler query with just `in` and see what happens.

Comment: AND vId in (select vId from table2 where colOne regexp "000|111|222") is where the query is breaking. The rest work fine!

Comment: can you show us the full query so we can understand where those table aliases come from?

Comment: you should provide the table definitions for table1 and table 2 to understand better